# When a user presses a button on my webpage, how can I send a request to a server to run a node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

Ok so I'm very new to web development and extremely new to servers as well. Basically, I have a webpage (using Firebase to Host) and when a user clicks the "Send SMS with link" button, I need to send an sms message.

Right now I'm using the Twilio Notify API to send an SMS, but it uses node.js. Like I said, I'm very new to web development, but from what I understand node.js can't be run from the browser, is that right?

If so, then I'm guessing I would need a server to run a node.js file. So, how would I send a request to a server (likely turning my computer into one) to run this twilio file and send the sms text message? Also, is it a good idea to turn my mac into a server or are there any other options (i know its a simple question)?

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are using this for some short time(like when you are on your PC, maybe learning to build websites), you can use your computer to [create a local node.js server](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/).
On the other hand, if you want to use that node.js server on any device or you are building a product/application for the users that must be running 24/7 then you may need to create the node.js server and then host it on a hosting platform like GoDaddy, Hostinger, etc.

P.S.: Heroku provides free hosting service, so you might wanna check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Node/Express template Twilio put together for Twilio Quest, which has this functionality built in (frontend/backend), you can take a look at.

**TwilioQuest** Starter Template Node

https://github.com/twilio/starter-node